# Pandas not able to read excel, due to error

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an error when reading this excel sheet.

[Survey of Professional Forecasters.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1isKgjbXwsq0mu7MHEo2rOPdcobnxeQQ0/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112640561557200108006&rtpof=true&sd=true)

## What I tried in Python

```py
spf = pd.read_excel(
    "ds/us/survey_of_professional_forecasters_all.xlsx"
)
```

Error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py:55, in _convert(expected_type, value)
     54 try:
---> 55     value = expected_type(value)
     56 except:

TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 spf = pd.read_excel(
      2     "ds/us/survey_of_professional_forecasters_all.xlsx"
      3 )
      4 spf

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:482, in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, decimal, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    480 if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    481     should_close = True
--> 482     io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    483 elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    484     raise ValueError(
    485         "Engine should not be specified when passing "
    486         "an ExcelFile - ExcelFile already has the engine set"
    487     )

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1695, in ExcelFile.__init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1692 self.engine = engine
   1693 self.storage_options = storage_options
-> 1695 self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py:557, in OpenpyxlReader.__init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    547 """
    548 Reader using openpyxl engine.
    549 
   (...)
    554 {storage_options}
    555 """
    556 import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
--> 557 super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:545, in BaseExcelReader.__init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    543 self.handles.handle.seek(0)
    544 try:
--> 545     self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
    546 except Exception:
    547     self.close()

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py:568, in OpenpyxlReader.load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    565 def load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer: FilePath | ReadBuffer[bytes]):
    566     from openpyxl import load_workbook
--> 568     return load_workbook(
    569         filepath_or_buffer, read_only=True, data_only=True, keep_links=False
    570     )

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py:317, in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    290 """Open the given filename and return the workbook
    291 
    292 :param filename: the path to open or a file-like object
   (...)
    313 
    314 """
    315 reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    316                     data_only, keep_links)
--> 317 reader.read()
    318 return reader.wb

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py:279, in ExcelReader.read(self)
    277 self.read_strings()
    278 self.read_workbook()
--> 279 self.read_properties()
    280 self.read_theme()
    281 apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py:173, in ExcelReader.read_properties(self)
    171 if ARC_CORE in self.valid_files:
    172     src = fromstring(self.archive.read(ARC_CORE))
--> 173     self.wb.properties = DocumentProperties.from_tree(src)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py:103, in Serialisable.from_tree(cls, node)
    100     else:
    101         attrib[tag] = obj
--> 103 return cls(**attrib)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\core.py:104, in DocumentProperties.__init__(self, category, contentStatus, keywords, lastModifiedBy, lastPrinted, revision, version, created, creator, description, identifier, language, modified, subject, title)
    102 self.creator = creator
    103 self.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy
--> 104 self.modified = modified
    105 self.created = created
    106 self.title = title

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py:268, in DateTime.__set__(self, instance, value)
    266     except ValueError:
    267         raise ValueError("Value must be ISO datetime format")
--> 268 super(DateTime, self).__set__(instance, value)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\nested.py:35, in Nested.__set__(self, instance, value)
     32         raise ValueError("Tag does not match attribute")
     34     value = self.from_tree(value)
---> 35 super(Nested, self).__set__(instance, value)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py:67, in Convertible.__set__(self, instance, value)
     64 def __set__(self, instance, value):
     65     if ((self.allow_none and value is not None)
     66         or not self.allow_none):
---> 67         value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
     68     super(Convertible, self).__set__(instance, value)

File D:\Programs\Python_Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py:57, in _convert(expected_type, value)
     55         value = expected_type(value)
     56     except:
---> 57         raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
     58 return value

TypeError: expected <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

## What worked

- Use 'Find and Replace' to replace all #N/A to blank in a sheet
- Open that particular sheet

Doing find and replace on all sheets did not work, as the program just crashes.

## Conclusion

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

pandas will look at the first few rows of your excel sheet and infer the types from that. Apparently somewhere in one of the sheets, there is a `datetime` in a column that pandas believes to be `int` which causes

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)
```

One solution to load the data would be

```
spf = pd.read_excel(
    "ds/us/survey_of_professional_forecasters_all.xlsx",
    dtype=object
)
```

This should essentially parse everything as string and then you can go through the columns one by one and make sure the types make sense with

```
spf.info()
```

The alternatively is exactly what you have been doing: Going through the original data and making sure they are correct.

Loading uncleaned data is always a lot of (manual) work unfortunately :(

Also it really helps to go through the table in small steps e.g. sheet by sheet with

```
spf = pd.read_excel(..., sheet_name=0)
```