# An integer is required (got type datetime.date) error with read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74170324/pandas-not-able-to-read-excel-due-to-error)

I'm trying to import [this excel file](https://www.philadelphiafed.org/-/media/frbp/assets/surveys-and-data/survey-of-professional-forecasters/data-files/files/mean_cpi10_level.xlsx) in pandas with the following script

```
url="https://www.philadelphiafed.org/-/media/frbp/assets/surveys-and-data/survey-of-professional-forecasters/data-files/files/mean_cpi10_level.xlsx"
df= pd.read_excel(url, index_col=0)
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py in _convert(expected_type, value)
     54         try:
---> 55             value = expected_type(value)
     56         except:

TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)
```

Following the answer to the previous question, I tried:

```
df = pd.read_excel(url, index_col=0, dtype={'YEAR': object, 'QUARTER': object, "CPI10": object})
```

and also (using openpyxl instead of pandas):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('mean_cpi10_level.xlsx')
```

but all resulted in the same error.
What can I do? Thanks?

Comment: Copy the values of the data to a new file, save it, and then load it.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that this file is part of an automated process I need to run on a regular basis, so if possible I'd like to avoid manual operations

Comment: If you want to automate your work, do not use Excel's technical features, such as freezing panes, when you create an Excel file. Instead, create a file that contains only data.

Comment: I'm not the creator of the excel file. It's a file published on the web, so I have no control on how it's made

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs it, I found out that with xlsx2csv I can easily convert the problematic xlsx to csv:

`Xlsx2csv("file.xlsx", outputencoding="utf-8").convert("file.csv")`

Also, polars seems to be able to read the file.